# Segmentation fault + questions

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

(code is not complete)

Im trying to learn to write in assembly but it seem quite complex so I have few question about it:

in this code (which for now doesnt do much anything at all but in the near future it will take two integer and sum them) why when runned it does segmentation fault?

What I thought is take one byte at time until we get to 5 byte (and subtract from it '0') which is the space allocated by resub into eNum.

is Dword for bss variables in main code required to use them in mov mult ecc.? because if i dont use it will give some kind of error.
subtracting '0' ascii from one of the byte allocated in eNum (so one of the number) will it give the binary of it? so i guess 00000001 in case of a 1. in that case i just have to convert it to decimal.
I was trying to do it with eNum2 but it gives segmentation fault, can you help me?

except for syscalls can I use the general purpose registers as I like?

```
;instanziazione di variabili fisse
section .data
    FirstMSG db  "Enter the first number:", 0xA, 0xD ;dichiaro il messaggio // 0xA e 0xD -> new line
    lenFUserMsg equ $-FirstMSG ;lunghezza del messaggio
    SecondMSG db "Enter the second number:", 0xA, 0xD
    lenSUserMsg equ $-SecondMSG ;lunghezza del messaggio
    counter db 0
 
;instanziazione di dati non inizializzati
section .bss
    eNum resb 5 ;alloca 5 byte
    eNum2 resb 5;
    

;dove inizia il programma
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ;andiamo a stampare il messaggio 
    mov rax, 1   ;in rax di solito si mettono i gli identificativi per le syscall
    mov rdi, 1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov rsi, FirstMSG     
    mov rdx, lenFUserMsg   ;rbx 
    syscall    ;chiamo il kernel

    ;andiamo a leggere dalla tastiera
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 2
    mov rsi, eNum      
    mov rdx, 5
    syscall

    ;leggiamo il secondo numero

    ;andiamo a stampare il messaggio 
    mov rax, 1   ;in rax di solito si mettono i gli identificativi per le syscall
    mov rdi, 1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov rsi, SecondMSG     
    mov rdx, lenSUserMsg   ;rbx 
    syscall    ;chiamo il kernel

    ;andiamo a leggere dalla tastiera
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 2
    mov rsi, eNum2      
    mov rdx, 5
    syscall

    movzx rsi, byte[eNum]
    sub rsi, '0'
    cmp al, 9
    jbe While

    ;chiudiamo il programma adesso
    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 80h

While:
    cmp dword [counter], 5
    je End
    inc byte [eNum]
    movzx rcx, byte[eNum]
    sub rcx, '0'
    add rsi, rcx
    inc dword [counter]
    jmp While

End:
   ;andiamo a stampare il messaggio 
    mov rax, 1   ;in rax di solito si mettono i gli identificativi per le syscall
    mov rdi, 1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov rdx, 1   ;rbx 
    syscall    ;chiamo il kernel

    ;chiudiamo il programma adesso
    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 80h
```

Comment: One important skill you want to develop when coding is useful problem reporting. "why when runned it does segmentation fault?" is descriptive in one sense, but you fail to share with us where in the code this occurs -- this kind of error occurs on one single offending instruction, then stops the program there.  Knowing what instruction causes the fault is usually really important.

Comment: Single step debugging is another important skill to develop for coding, and, it's easy: step one line at a time and verify your expectations, including register values, memory values, and control flow.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
inc dword [counter]
```

but earlier, it's only one byte

```
counter db 0
```

So you are corrupting something else. You also have

```
cmp dword [counter], 5
```

so it looks as though you intended the storage to be

```
counter dw 0
```

or, to use the `byte` directive for the instruction's operand size.

Comment: `dw 0` is one data-word, 2 bytes.  `dd 0` is a data dword.  (Or the first d might stand for "define", but not double)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, although the `db` is still incorrect.

Comment: Yes, of course.  Much better would be using a register instead of static storage at all!  The `While:` loop looks seriously over-complicated.

Comment: why inc [counter] is not accepted?

Comment: It needs the size of the target, like `byte` or `dword` or whatever you decide it needs to be.